# Two-factor authentication for Wi-Fi?

Tags: cisco, wireless, authentication

We have a new requirement to have two-factor authentication for a certain SSIDs in our enterprise. Currently we run PEAP-MSCHAPv2 to pass windows credentials to a RADIUS server (NPS running on a domain controller) and Cisco 1142 WAPs (all autonomous, no WLC in place).

What are some methods of two-factor authentication for Wi-Fi SSIDs? I am aware of setting up an authentication proxy (e.g. RSA, etc.). However, would like to know if there are other options, and which, if any in your experience, are more common?

Comment: Would EAP-TTLS using client certificates work as two factor if you use MS-CHAPv2 as the inner auth?  This would mean that to authenticate a client must both have something (a cert) and know something (username/password).

Comment: So - that is what we want to do - but from the NPS side, we can add those methods MSCHAPv2, and then EAP-TLS for certs, to the same network connection policy but it looks to be a processing order, not a set of cumulative requirements.  That's why I was asking about other options built at the AP level since it seems to be a limitation of NPS.  Bearing in mind of course NPS can still do true 2-factor with tokens, but we're looking for other ways (namely EAP-TLS + MSCHAPv2).  Thanks for feedback so far.

Comment: EAP-TTLS is not EAP-TLS.  EAP-TTLS is somewhat like PEAP in that it builds a tunnel to pass the inner authentication but it has the option to use a client certificate as well that PEAP does not.  One of the major drawbacks for EAP-TTLS is that it wasn't supported natively in Windows, but they added this support in Windows 8.

Comment: Good info, I was saying the same just misspelling it, leaving open for more feedback / solutions - thanks for your suggestions.